# chart.js v3: How to align gridlines with stepsizes?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

Expected:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXRSX.png)

Current:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmTD8.png)

I want to have stepsizes and gridlines in the same line and some padding

How can i achieve that with chart.js v3

```
scales: {
                y: {
                    stacked: true,
                    grid: {
                        offset: true,
                        display: true,
                        drawBorder: false,
                        drawOnChartArea: true,
                        borderDashOffset: 25,
                        borderColor: "#d1d2db",
                        borderWidth: 0.8800000000000001,
                        color: "#d1d2db",
                    },
                    min: 0,
                    max: max,
                    ticks: {
                        // forces step size to be 25 units
                        stepSize: 25,
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        callback: callback,
                        max: max,
                    },
                    title: {
                        display: false,
                        text: "Y axis title",
                    },
                },

                x: {
                    grid: {
                        offset: true,
                        display: true,
                        drawBorder: false,
                        drawOnChartArea: false,
                        drawTicks: false,
                        tickLength: 0,
                        // borderDash: [0, 1],
                        // borderDashOffset: 0,
                        borderColor: "#d1d2db",
                        // borderWidth: 0.8800000000000001,
                        color: "#d1d2db",
                    },
                },
            },
```

Btw, is it also possible to have perpendiculars from data points to x-axis as shown in expected design ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have the horizontal `grid` lines aligned with the y labels, define  `options.scales.y.grid.offset: false` or omit the option.

For the vertical lines from the bottom of the chart up to individual data points, you can use the [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api). In the `afterDraw` hook for example, you can draw the lines directly on the `canvas` using the [`CanvasRenderingContext2D`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D).

Please take a look at your amended and runnable code and see how it works.

```js
new Chart('chart', {
  type: 'line',
  plugins: [{
    afterDraw: chart => {
      var ctx = chart.ctx;
      ctx.save();
      var xAxis = chart.scales.x;
      var yAxis = chart.scales.y;
      const data = chart.data.datasets[0].data;
      xAxis.ticks.forEach((v, i) => {
        var x = xAxis.getPixelForTick(i);
        var yTop = yAxis.getPixelForValue(data[i]);        
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#aaaaaa';
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x, yAxis.bottom);
        ctx.lineTo(x, yTop);
        ctx.stroke();        
      });
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }],
  data: {
    labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My Data',
      data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 68],
      borderColor: '#0a0'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        stacked: true,
        grid: {
          display: true,
          drawBorder: false,
          drawOnChartArea: true,
          borderDashOffset: 25,
          borderColor: "#d1d2db",
          borderWidth: 0.8800000000000001,
          color: "#d1d2db",
        },
        min: 0,
        ticks: {
          stepSize: 25,
          beginAtZero: true,
        },
        title: {
          display: false,
          text: "Y axis title",
        },
      },
      x: {
        grid: {
          offset: true,
          display: true,
          drawBorder: false,
          drawOnChartArea: false,
          drawTicks: false,
          tickLength: 0,
          borderColor: "#d1d2db",
          color: "#d1d2db",
        },
      },
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.8.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" width="400" height="95"></canvas>
```